# Grease Pencil Render border missing

Tags: grease-pencil

When I started drawing/ animating each frame there was a border that showed where the rendered view would end. Recently it disappeared and I am wondering how to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the camera view - <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>  (if you have a camera)